# GaeUtilities: Session Problem

Tags: google-app-engine, session

I'm programming an application with google app engine, with django 1.1 (no django pacth or others), well as you know is impossible use django login and session features so I download
Gae utility and use Session Object (http://gaeutilities.appspot.com/) but some time this object create 2 sessions instead 1 session ... here's code

```
def index(request):

     aSWrap = SWrap(SWrap.createSession())
     ....
      def login(request):

     aSWrap = SWrap(SWrap.createSession())
     ....


      class SWrap(object):

   @classmethod    
   def createSession():

     return Session(cookie_name='my_cookie',session_expire_time=7200)
```

and for setting session no expiration or really long expiration...`enter code here`
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a different sessions library.  Check out [this comparison of the available sessions libraries for GAE](http://wiki.github.com/dound/gae-sessions/comparison-with-alternative-libraries).

I'd recommend [gae-sessions](http://wiki.github.com/dound/gae-sessions/) - it presents an API almost identical to the library you are currently using, but it is much faster and shouldn't give you headaches like the bug you've encountered above.

Disclaimer: I wrote gae-sessions, but I'm not the only one who would recommend it.  Here is a [recent thread discussing sessions](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/2fd96bbfe11de0eb) on the google group for GAE python.

Comment: wow thanks I will try it soon, and thanks to share your library

Comment: and is it strong like gaeutilities? I mean about security issue

Comment: Yes, they are both equally resistant to session hijacking and fixation attacks (and the same with other session libraries).  Of course all of them all vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks unless your users are connected over a secure channel (HTTPS).  So use HTTPS (or switch to HTTPS and change the session ID) for portions of your site where security is paramount (just like Amazon and others do).

Comment: ok, great I'm already switching to your session lib it's great thanks

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the code, you're calling createsession twice within the same request. That will cause problems with David's library as well.

Also, gaeutilties session included a config file where you can modify all the default values as you like.

https://github.com/joerussbowman/gaeutilities/blob/master/appengine_utilities/settings_default.py

gaeutilities session also has security features lacking in gae-sessions. I'm afraid David didn't attempt to answer you question, rather just suggested you use his library which under your current implementation would have the exact same problem. You need to be sure you only initiate the session once per http request no matter what session library you're using.

I'm moving gaeutilities session to a decorator in order to address this issue as well and provide better performance. You can watch the master branch on Github for updates. https://github.com/joerussbowman/gaeutilities

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with `SWrap(SWrap.createSession())`?  It looks like the result of `SWrap.createSession()` is passed to the `SWrap()` constructor.  Have you omitted part of the definition of `SWrap`?

Perhaps this is more what you are wanting:

```
def index(request):
    mysession = SWrap.createSession()
    ....

def login(request):
    mysession = SWrap.createSession()
    ....

class SWrap(object):
    @staticmethod    
    def createSession():
        return Session(cookie_name='my_cookie',session_expire_time=7200)
```

Comment: yes I've omitted, before I've tried to put create session into constructor but don't works at all :) thanks for the answer